# File read issue in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using `camel` in my application. My client will place his files in my server folder using SFTP. My application will then process the files. Sometimes he puts big files, and my application reads the file while they're being written into my server folder.

To solve this issue my friends suggest 2 options:

1. readLock=changed
2. preMove.

Which is correct in my case?

```
from("file://target/input")
```

Comment: Test them both and then decide on which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use both options for good result. readLock will ensure that file will not be read while it is being written and preMove will be move the file to staging folder to avoid multi time access.

**from("file://target/input&preMove=staging&readLock=changed")**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readLock=changed` together with `readLockMinAge`.

And maybe there is a third option, when your client can place a ready-file too.